# combinatorics for buying a new car

Tags: combinatorics

Question: Mindy is buying a new car. for the car she has selected the following options are available: power windows, a sunroof, and leather interior. if she must select one or more of these options, how many different combinations of options can she select?

My attempt: $3x2x1$

I don't know how to express if possibilities if she can choose one option, two options, or all 3 options .

Comment: Did you try doing a tree graph depending on whether shee took the windows or not, then the sunroof or not, and then the leather or not=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be $3 \times 2 \times 1$: this counts the number of permutations of $\{\text{power windows},\text{sunroof},\text{leather interior}\}$.  (Perhaps this is the number of orderings in which they could be installed?)

The number of ways of choosing one option is $\binom{3}{1}$.  The number of ways of choosing two options is $\binom{3}{2}$.  The number of ways of choosing three options is $\binom{3}{3}$.  So, the number of ways of not choosing zero options is the sum of these.

However, there's a better way:  each option is a Yes/No choice:

- Power windows: Yes or No.
- Sunroof: Yes or No.
- Leather interior: Yes or No.

So there are $2 \times 2 \times 2$ possibilities in total, and we just have to exclude the case where she says No to all of them.

Comment: why can't you use nCr for the following problem: Karen is ordering a hamburger. The restaurant offers
2 different kinds of bread, 3 different condiments, and
2 different kinds of cheese. If Karen selects one type
of bread, one condiment, and one type of cheese, how
many ways can she order her burger?

Comment: We both can and should use combinations for that problem: $\binom{2}{1} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1}$.  We choose one type of bread, one condiment, and one type of cheese.

Comment: I understand. i forgot to multiply; i didn't realize the choices were mutually exclusive